# sed remove trailing space after bracket

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to remove trailing space after brackets in an HTML file using sed (part of a shell script on CentOS):

from this:

```
<p>Some text (
<em>Text which should not break to a new line</em>). More text.</p>
```

to this:

```
<p>Some text (<em>Text which should not break to a new line</em>). More text.</p>
```

I can easily do it in Sublime Text with `\(\s` REGEX and replacing it with a bracket but this does not work in sed.

I have tried:

```
sed 's/[(]\s*$/(/'
sed 's/[(]\s*$\n/(/'
```

and many other things, but none of them work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean remove the newline ?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
sed ':a;/($/{N;s/\n//;ba}' file
```

If the line ends with `(`, appends the next line (`N`) to the pattern space and then substitutes the newline character `\n` with nothing, thereby joining the lines. This is done in a loop (`ba` jumps back to label `a`).

Comment: why should jumps back to label? and what is `b` in `ba`?

Comment: Check the `sed` manual. `a` is a label and `b label` means "Branch to label". This creates a loop.

Comment: thank you,, i delete `:a` and `ba` from your code, and result is same; why you use label?

Comment: Try testing it with a file which has three consecutive lines ending with `(`. They won't get joined into one single line if you don't use the loop.

Comment: Thanks, this almost worked. It moved the line up but did not remove the space, so I amended it a little: `':a;/( $/{N;s/( /(/;s/\n//;ba}'`.

If I may just ask one more question: for me syntax `sed 'transformation' file` does not work – I always have to specify `sed 'transformation' file > new_file`. Can you advise?

Comment: You mean `sed 'transformation' file` does not print anything to your terminal (stdout)?

Comment: `sed 'transformation' file` does not change the `file` itself, which in my case is an .html, but only prints the output to the terminal. Is there a way for sed to make changes in the input file?

Comment: Use the `-i` option to update the file i.e. `sed -i transformation file`

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
awk 'sub(/\(\s*$/,"("){printf "%s",$0;next}7' file
```

an example with/without trailing spaces/tab:

```
kent$  cat f
foo [with trailing spaces](     
)foo end
bar [with trailing spaces & tab](               
)bar end
blah no trailing spaces(
)
```

just to show the trailing spaces:

```
kent$  sed 's/$/|/' f
foo [with trailing spaces](     |
)foo end|
bar [with trailing spaces & tab](               |
)bar end|
blah no trailing spaces(|
)|
```

test with my awk oneliner:

```
kent$  awk 'sub(/\(\s*$/,"("){printf "%s",$0;next}7' f
foo [with trailing spaces]()foo end
bar [with trailing spaces & tab]()bar end
blah no trailing spaces()
```

Comment: what is `7` at the the end?

Comment: just an alternative for print.

Comment: @Babyy a non-zero number will be considered as boolean `true` in awk. and trigger the default action, which is print. I feel it is easier to press `7`, you can give `1`, `8`, or `134123142`

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue once. `tr` is the way to go here instead of `sed`:

`cat textfile.ext | tr -d '\n'`

which will delete all linebreaks (`-d`) of your file. Or you may even filter out the regarding lines first with `grep` eg.

`cat textfile.ext | grep -A1 '^<p>Some text' | tr -d '\n'`

The option `-A1` stands for `n` lines After the one you cached with your regexp `'^<p>...` . See `man grep` for a more detailed explanation.

EDIT: On your special case the `grep` command should more likely look like this: `grep -A1 '($'`, which filters all opening parents at the end of a row with its following line (see above).